# jQuery Timepicker time field format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-timepicker

I am using jQuery Timepicker [here](http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/), now in my time textbox, I get time as `HH:MM:SS` format, but i want it in `HH:MM` format.

I have tried various `timeformat` in default initialization, setting `showsecond` as false but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using jQuery >= 1.7?

There is no option *showsecond* in the documentation at [GitHub](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery)

Did you try:

```
$('#timeformatExample1').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i' });
```

Comment: Thanks Amani, i was only looking at default initialization page and from your code found timeformat can also be declared where we bind timepicker with control

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this statement, which is working very well for me:

```
$('#timeformatExample1').timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'h:mm' });
```